# CSS counter-reset only works inside the same box?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage on which will appear numbered problems and lettered subproblems. But the format isn't super strict. Sometimes the subproblems will be in the same paragraph as the main problem, sometimes they'll be in a following paragraph. (Or they might show up in a list or each in their own paragraph.)

So I have span.problem and span.subproblem. I'm setting a counter called "problem", which is reset in the body element and incremented every time a span.problem occurs (technically "before" the span.problem). I'm also setting a "subproblem" counter which is reset initially in the body element, but also in every span.problem element. It's incremented before every span.subproblem element.

The problem seems to be that the counter-reset on the subproblem counter seems to only work the way I expect it to when the span.problem element is inside the same paragraph as the span.subproblem elements.

Here's a minimalish example:

**CSS**

```
body {
 counter-reset: problem, subproblem;
}

span.problem:before {
 counter-increment: problem;
 content: "Problem " counter(problem) ": ";
}

span.problem {
 counter-reset: subproblem;
}

span.subproblem:before {
 counter-increment: subproblem;
 content: "(" counter(subproblem, lower-alpha) ") ";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel=stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<p>Some text leading up to: <span class=problem>do the first problem.</span> Now this is in the same paragraph as <span class=subproblem> the first subproblem</span>and <span class=subproblem>the second subproblem.</span></p>

<p>The <span class=subproblem>third subproblem</span> is in its own paragraph.</p>

<p>Later on, you'll want to <span class=problem> do the second main problem</span>, but all the subproblems will be in another paragraph.</p>

<p>The second paragraph has <span class=subproblem>a subproblem here</span> and <span class=subproblem>here</span>.</p>

</body> 
</html>
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve what I'm going for?

Comment: You haven't said what you expect. Can you show, as plain text, the output you expect it to render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/042hu9ss/) will give you a start.

The general idea about counters is to put the 'reset' line in the that element in which you want every counter to start over.

So in this particular case, the main problem counter should only be reset at the top of the page, and incremented for every mainproblem class.

The subproblem should be reset at the top of the page, but then reset at the beginning of each mainproblem class, and incremented for every subproblem class.

I added some boring styling just to make some of the text easier to see.

CSS

```
body {
    counter-reset: problem, subproblem;
}
.mainproblem {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    counter-reset: subproblem 0;
    counter-increment: problem;
}
.problem:before {
    content: "Problem " counter(problem) ": ";
    color: red;
}
.subproblem:before {
    counter-increment: subproblem;
    content: "(" counter(subproblem, lower-alpha) ") ";
    color: blue;
}
```

---

Edit: An attempt at a clearer statement - assuming that we are counting based upon differences in "class".

1. All counters are given names, and should be reset at the top of CSS.
2. Assume you have a series of classes named "problem" and you want to increment the problem number for each time you see a class of "problem". Reset the problem counter at the top of the page under body, and then in the .problem css add "counter-increment: problem".
3. Assume you have a series of classes named "subproblem" that are always under the "problem" class. Everytime you have a new "problem" class, you need to reset the counter - so under ".problem" you add "counter-reset: subproblem". and under ".subproblem" you add "counter-increment: subproblem".

Comment: Ah, I can see how that would work.

Just to be sure I understand: add a div to contain each problem (including its subproblems), and reset the subproblem counter there.

Comment: Just modified my answer